The area of a inscribed polygon tends to the area of the circle
As it is broadly known, given a circle of radius $r$, its area is equal to $\pi \cdot r^2$. My goal is to prove this formula using inscribed polygons.
Let´s call $n$ the number of sides of a regular polygon inscribed in a circle of radius $r$, and each of the sides have a length of $\ell$. As $n$ gets larger, as we consider always the same circle, $\ell$ gets smaller, and on each step we get a polygon that is closer and closer to the circle; in the limit we expect to get the area of such circle, $\pi \cdot r^2$.

The area of a regular polygon is known to be $A = \frac{Perimeter \cdot Apothem}{2}$, which is easily obtained by triangulation. We can indeed obtain a formula which only depends on $n$ and $\ell$:

The perimeter, since the polygon is regular, is $n\cdot \ell$
We can divide the polygon in $n$ isosceles triangles, each of then having one angle of $\frac{2\pi}{n}$, two sides of length $r$ and a base of lenght $\ell$. If we divide the triangles in half using the apothem, we get right triangles where we can obtain the relation $$\tan(\frac{\pi}{n}) = \frac{\frac{\ell}{2}}{Apothem} \Leftrightarrow Apothem = \frac{\ell}{2\cdot \tan(\frac{\pi}{n})}$$

Therefore, the area of the polygon is $$A=\frac{n \cdot \ell^2}{4\cdot \tan(\frac{\pi}{n})}$$
From this formula, let´s tend $n$ to infinity and $\ell$ to $0$, and I expect to get the area of the circle. I have to solve then:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty, \ell \to 0} \frac{n \cdot \ell^2}{4\cdot \tan(\frac{\pi}{n})}$$
Changing the variable $n$ to $m=\frac{1}{n}$:
$$\lim_{m\to 0, \ell \to 0} \frac{\ell^2}{4\cdot m\cdot \tan(\pi \cdot m)}$$
We know than $tan(x) \to x$ as $ x \to 0$; therefore we get
$$\lim_{m\to 0, \ell \to 0} \frac{\ell^2}{4\cdot m \cdot \pi \cdot m} = \frac{1}{4\pi} \lim_{m\to 0, \ell \to 0} \frac{\ell^2}{m^2}$$
However, I found out that the resulting limit does not exist.
Intuitively, the limit should tend to the area of the circle, but I don´t know where my mistake is.

I haven't checked all the calculations but your last limit is undefined, meaning that you need to do more work to find the limit (like expressing $l$ in function of $m$). There is a big difference between a limit not existing and a limit being undefined.

So, a potential issue I'm noticing arises here:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty, \ell \to 0} \frac{n \cdot \ell^2}{4\cdot \tan(\frac{\pi}{n})}$$
In this phrasing, $\ell$ is treated as an independent variable, when it's not: it is dependent on $n$ and cannot be freely varied. Therefore, you really should seek to find
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n \ell(n)}{4 \tan(\frac \pi n)}
$$
whilst knowing that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \ell(n) = 0
$$
I may return later to think further on this; for now I have to leave a coffee shop I'm at.

(Addendum: my limit above should have $n \ell^2(n)$ in the numerator.)

The polygons in the diagram are inscribed, not circumscribed.

@MishaLavrov you are right, I’ll update it. Sorry for my English.

As PrincessEev says in the comments, the issue is exactly that $\ell$ is not something you can freely vary but is a function of $n$ and $r$. Actually it makes the computation work out slightly nicer to define $\ell$ to be half the side length. Using that division of the regular polygon into $n$ isosceles triangles and dropping the altitude you mentioned it's not hard to show that
$$\ell = r \sin \frac{\pi}{n}$$
and that the apothem is $h = r \cos \frac{\pi}{n}$. This gives a total area of
$$A = n \ell h = \boxed{ nr^2 \sin \frac{\pi}{n} \cos \frac{\pi}{n} } = \frac{nr^2 \sin \frac{2 \pi}{n}}{2}$$
which you can see converges to $\pi r^2$ using the familiar limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.
Note also that the perimeter of the inscribed regular $n$-gon is $2n \ell = 2nr \sin \frac{\pi}{n}$. It should be pretty intuitive that as $n \to \infty$ the value of $\ell$ is asymptotic to $\frac{\pi r}{n}$ since for large $n$ it is approximately just $\frac{1}{2n}$ of the circumference, so taking $n \to \infty$ also gives us that the perimeters converge to the circumference $C = 2 \pi r$ of a circle as expected.
Trigonometry can be avoided here by repeatedly doubling $n$ and working out what this does to $\ell$ and $h$; this was what Archimedes did and it can be used to approximate $\pi$.

Thanks so much!!!!
